# Playing Cards: Formula for match probability with card draw rules

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, card-games

This is a simplification of a larger problem I have been working on, calculating probabilities based upon a characteristic, with rules for selection based upon a second characteristic.  I believe if I can, with your help, determine the correct calculation method for this problem I can then expand it to my larger problem.  Thanks in advance!

**Setup:**

With a deck of 8 cards: ( Ace Clubs Black [ACb], Ace Diamonds Red [ADr], Ace Hearts Red [AHr], Ace Spades Black [ASb], King Clubs Black [KCb], King Diamonds Red [KDr], King Hearts Red [KHr], and King Spades Black [KSb].

Therefore: the deck is (ACb, ADr, AHr, ASb, KCr, KDr KHr, KSb) arranged in fair random order.

**Draw Rules:**

Draw, without replacement, up to 4 cards.  Stop drawing as soon as you have drawn 2 Aces or have drawn the 4th card.

**Question:**

What is the probability P(A) of drawing exactly 2 black cards and the KHr card?  Extra card, if drawn, must be red.

**Expected result** (derived from counting of the exhaustive list of possibilities):
$$P(A) = {296\over 1680} = {37\over 210}\approx 0.17619$$

---

I need help developing generalized approach, as the underlying problem I am trying to solve has $_{416}P_6 \approx 5.0E6$ permutations, so full list enumeration and counting is not practical.

---

Here's how I have been calculating it, but I have gotten stuck.

[EDIT:]
 Upon reflection it seems each of the 5 hand options could each be treated like a pick from bags problem:

E.g.  You have 2 bags (A, K).

Bag A contains 2 black beads and 2 red beads.  Bag K contains 2 black beads, 1 red beads, and one green bead.

For hand "AAK", draw 2 from bag A and 1 from bag K.  What is the probability P(G<sub>2</sub>) that what you draw is B, B, G?  $$P(G_2) = \left(\frac{2}{4}\right)\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right ) = 0.125$$
$$P(B_2) = \left(\frac{240}{1680}\right)$$
Then multiply this probability with the P(B<sub>2</sub>) to get the final hand probability.
$$P(H_2) = P(B_2) * P(G_2) = \left(\frac{240}{1680}\right)*\left(\frac{1}
{8}\right) = \left(\frac{240}{13440}\right) \approx 1.785714E-2$$ and then sum all together $$P(A) = \sum_{i=0}^5 P(G_i)P(B_i)$$

Does that seem correct?

[/EDIT:]

---

**Known permutation facts:**

Total Permutations of 4 cards:  $T_p = _8P_4 = 1680$

Possible hands drawn, sorted by rank, and their permutations (items in brackets are assumption that the undrawn cards can be any of the remaining):

1. AA: $B_1 = _4P_2 * [_6P_2] * 1 = 360$   Hands: AAxx
2. AAK: $B_2 = _4P_2 * _4P_1 * [_5P_1] * 2 = 240$ Hands: AKAx, KAAx
3. AAKK: $B_3 = _4P_2 * _4P_2 * 3 = 432$ Hands: AKAK, AKKA, KKAA
4. AKKK: $B_4 = _4P_1 * _4P_3 * 4 = 384$ Hands: AKKK, KAKK, KKAK, KKKA
5. KKKK: $B_5 = _4P_4 * 1 = 24$ Hands: KKKK

Probability of the hand n:  $P(B_n) = {B_n\over T_P}$

Permutations of desired outcome H (of 4 black pick 2, of 1 KHr pick 1, of 3 red pick 1, all permutations):  $H_P = \binom{4}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1}*(_4P_4) = 432$

**And this is where I am having difficulty:**

Permutations based upon drawn hand Bn, where for nCr $\binom{n}{r}$ when r=n nCr = 1, when r>n, nCr = 0.

1. For B<sub>1</sub> [AA]: $H_1 = \binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{0}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{2} * (_4P_4)  = 0$ 
   Of the 2 Aces, Pick 2 and of those, pick from the 2 black. Of the 0 Kings, pick 1... Impossible
2. For B<sub>2</sub> [AAK]: $H_2 = \binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{1} * (_4P_4) = 120$
   All Permutations 4P4
3. For B<sub>3</sub> [AAKK]: $H_3 = \left(\binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} \right) * (_4P_4) = 168$ 
   Pick 2 black from the aces, 1 KHr, and one Kr.  OR  Pick 1 black from the aces, 1 red from the aces, 1 black from the kings, and 1 KHr.  All permutations 4P4.
4. For B<sub>4</sub> [AKKK]:  $H_4 = \left(\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}\right) * (_4P_4) = 144$
   Pick 1 black from the 2 for Aces, pick 1 black for the 2 for kings, pick 1 from KHr, and 1 from the remaining Kr OR pick 1 from the 2 red Aces, 2 from the 2 black kings, 1 from KHr and 1 Kr.  All permutation 4P4
5. For B<sub>5</sub> [KKKK]:  $H_5 = \binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1} * (_4P_4) = 24$
    Of the kings, pick 2 of the 2 blacks, of the remaining kings, pick the 1 KHr, of the remaining 1, pick 1.  All permutations 4P4.

The confusion I have is how to go from the H<sub>n</sub> value combined with P(B<sub>n</sub>) to derive the expected value for P(A). If it is $P(B_n|H_n)$ then I don't know the divisor for $B_n$

As a check:  The list enumerated quantities of H<sub>n</sub>|B<sub>n</sub> are:

1. $H_1 = 0$
2. $H_2 = 20$
3. $H_3 = 108$
4. $H_4 = 144$
5. $H_5 = 24$

---

Thank you for assistance.   This is a re-ask of this problem, as my last attempt at the question was down voted twice without comment, so I have completely re-written it.  If you do feel this is worthy of a down vote, can I please ask for the favor of a comment of advice on how to clarify the scenario to make it more acceptable.  Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask what the larger problem is?

Comment: Is computer enumeration and evaluation of the larger problem impractical for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my confusion and developed the universal formula to solve this problem, so I am closing this question